Décalage as a model for a path space object?
I am wondering how one can view a (plain) décalage of a simplicial space (or at least a simplicial set) $X$ as its path space object in the sense of the model category theory. Although this is what I would expect from the very first sentence of the nLab article (decalage) I somehow struggle to find an appropriate triple of structure morphisms.
Main question: Is a décalage of a simplicial set a path space object in the sense of the model category theory? If so, how explicitly can be the diagonal $\Delta: X \to X \times X$ factorised as to obtain a weak equivalence $f: X \to \mathbf{Dec}_0 (X)$ and $g: \mathbf{Dec}_0 (X) \to X \times X$?
Side remark: I seem there is actually two different notions of a path space object -- based and un-based. I am hesitating not to think that only un-based type of path spaces are convenient candidates for path space objects in the sense of a model category theory. As a matter of the fact the space $\mathbf{Dec}_0(X)$ is considered (decalage) to be a union of based path space objects for all points of $X$. But I can see no difference of such unions from un-based path space objects either.
Side question: If the main answer is yes -- $\mathbf{Dec}_0(X)$ can be seen as a path space object for $X$ in the category of simplicial sets, is it then possible to extend this statement from a model category of simplicial sets to a model category of simplicial presheaves? If not, why essentially?
I will appreciate any hint or a relevant reference!
